# How to auto adjust the <div> height according to content in it?

Tags: css, html

I have a `<div>` which needs to be auto adjusted according to the content in it.  How can I do this?  Right now my content is coming out of the `<div>`

The class I have used for the div is as follows

```
box-centerside  {
background:url("../images/greybox-center-bg1.jpg") repeat-x scroll center top transparent;
float:left;
height:100px;
width:260px;
}
```

Comment: Neither Height:auto is working for me nor min-height: working for me, i am using mozilla firefox, latest version

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try with the following mark-up instead of directly specifying height:

```css
.box-centerside {
  background: url("../images/greybox-center-bg1.jpg") repeat-x scroll center top transparent;
  float: left;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 260px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-centerside">
  This is sample content<br>
  This is sample content<br>
  This is sample content<br>
  This is sample content<br>
  This is sample content<br>
  This is sample content<br>
  This is sample content<br>
  This is sample content<br>
  This is sample content<br>
  This is sample content<br>
  This is sample content<br>
  This is sample content<br>
</div>
```

Comment: if someone is still using ie6 its their own fault its broken... << I may think it but i still have to support that garbage... or at least the content has to survive....

Comment: I agree with Walterj89, however I also disagree - IE6 *should* be supported at least until IE9 comes out properly. In general I don't think anyone should support IE.

Comment: Neither Height:auto is working for me nor min-height: working for me, i am using mozilla firefox, latest version

Comment: This works fine on my FireFox 3.6 and IE8 - what version of FireFox are you running?

Comment: I dont why but suddenly it gave me the output i needed.. thanx for ur help bud...

Comment: I did the same for my scenario same as the question but i am having a list of images inside that popup for one image it is fitting exactly another image size is small but am getting more white space below the image... Any idea?

Answer (score 100):

Just write "min-height: XXX;" And "overflow: hidden;" & you will be out of this problem
Like this

```
min-height: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: Neat trick, thanks. One side question. Would this still work say if I bring in some more content to teh page using PHP or AJAX, will the page expands to fit the contents height?

Comment: I've been 10years doing this job and I've been all this time wondering to solve/prevent this! Thanks a million!

Comment: It is my pleasure friends.

Comment: I would love to understand the rationale of this counter-intuitive solution. How does CSS justify `overflow: hidden;` letting me **see more** of something? (In my case, without it, the containing block shrinks to its height, and content appears truncated at the bottom.)

Comment: Worked immediately and was exactly right.  I had tried all sorts of things, none of which worked, but this did it.

Comment: Even this doesnt work for me. Setting min-height and/or overflow:hidden doesnt work for me. The div just doesnt expand.

Answer (score 21):

Just write:

```
min-height: xxx;
overflow: hidden;
```

then `div` will automatically take the height of the content.

Answer (score 16):

I've used the following in the DIV that needs to be resized:

```
overflow: hidden;
height: 1%;
```

Answer (score 14):

You could try, div tag will auto fit height with content inside:

```
height: fit-content;
```

Answer (score 9):

just use following

```
height:auto;
```

Comment: Great answer, though unless there is a conflicting declaration higher in the tree, `height` will imply as `auto` by default.

Comment: Neither Height:auto is working for me nor min-height: working for me, i am using mozilla firefox, latest version

Comment: -ve that gives me vertical scrollbar, that i dont want

Answer (score 9):

I have made some reach to do auto adjust of height for my project and I think I found a solution

```
[CSS]
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
```

This can be attached to prime `div` (e.g. warpper, but not to `body` or `html` cause the page will not scroll down) in your css file and inherited by other child classes and write into them `overflow: inherit;` attribute.

Notice: Odd thing is that my netbeans 7.2.1 IDE highlight `overflow: inherit;` as `Unexpected value token inherit` but all modern browser read this attribute fine.

This solution work very well into

- firefox 18+
- chorme 24+
- ie 9+
- opera 12+

I do not test it on previous versions of those browsers. If someone will check it, it will be nice.

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't gotten the answer yet, your "float:left;" is messing up what you want.  In your HTML create a container below your closing tags that have floating applied.  For this container, include this as your style:

```
#container {
clear:both;
}
```

Done.

Answer (score 3):

Don't set `height`. Use `min-height` and `max-height` instead.

Comment: Neither Height:auto is working for me nor min-height: working for me, i am using mozilla firefox, latest version

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer is to use `overflow: hidden` and `min-height: x(any) px` which will auto-adjust the size of div.

The `height: auto` won't work.

Answer (score 2):

simply set the height to auto, that should fix the problem, because div are block elements so they stretch out to full width and height of any element contained in it. if height set to auto not working then simple don't add the height, it should adjust and make sure that the div is not inheriting any height from it's parent element as well...

Answer (score 1):

Set a height to the last placeholder div.

```
    <div class="row" style="height:30px;">
    <!--placeholder to make the whole block has valid auto height-->
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Min- Height : (some Value) units
```

---- Use **only** this incase of elements where you cannot use overflow, like **tooltip**

Else you can use *overflow property* or *min-height* according to your need.

Answer (score 1):

I just used

```
overflow: hidden;
```

And it was worked for me properly. This div had some of float lefted divs.

Comment: Worked for me too. I combined it with height:auto; and display:block;

Answer (score 1):

Most of these are great answers, but I feel that they are leaving out one inevitable aspect of web-development which is the on-going page update. What if you want to come and add content to this div? Should you always come to adjust the div min-height? Well, whilst trying to answer these two questions, I tried out the following code instead:

```
.box-centerside {
  background: url("../images/greybox-center-bg1.jpg") repeat-x scroll center top transparent;
  float: left;
  height: auto; /* adjusts height container element according to content */
  width: 260px;
}
```

furthermore, just for a sort of bonus , if you have elements around this div with properties like `position: relative;` , they would consequently stack on top of this div, because it has property `float: left;` To avoid such stacking, I tried the following code:

```
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); /* number depends on how many columns you want for a particular screen width. */
  height: auto; /* adjusts height container element according to content */
}

.box-centerside {
  background: url("../images/greybox-center-bg1.jpg") repeat-x scroll center top transparent;
  height: auto; /* adjusts height container element according to content */
  width: 100%;
}

.sibling 1 {
  /* Code here */
}

.sibling 2 {
  /* Code here */
}
```

My opinion is that, I find this grid method of displaying more fitting for a responsive website. Otherwise, there are many ways of achieving the same goals; But some of the important goals of programming are to make coding simpler and more readable as well as easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to set such as `min-height` any more, only set work well:

```
overflow: hidden
```

Comment: I was working with bootstrap Modal box and loading a form in it was breaking it. Now with your suggestion, I put overflow to scroll and it works awesome.

Answer (score 0):

`<div>` should expand automatically. I guess that the problem is that you're using fixed `height:100px;`, try replacing it with `min-height:100px;`

Comment: Neither Height:auto is working for me nor min-height: working for me, i am using mozilla firefox, latest version

Comment: Like *Neurofluxation* said, you need to have `.` or `#` before `box-centerside` to match classes or IDs. At the moment, your code matches elements of node name `box-centerside` - of which none exists.

Comment: I am aware of that this code has been copied from firebug hence not displayed with "."

Answer (score 0):

use `min-height` instead of `height`

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my issue by setting the position of the element inside a div to relative;

Answer (score 0):

height:59.55%;//First specify your height then make overflow auto
overflow:auto;

Answer (score 0):

For me after trying everything the below css worked:

```
float: left; width: 800px;
```

Try in chrome by inspecting element before putting it in css file.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try Using `fit-content` This Works In Every Browser

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fit According To Div</title>

    <style>
        .test {
            /* Use This Code */
            width: fit-content;
            block-size: fit-content;
            /* You Can Also Try height: fit-content */
            height: auto;

            border-radius: 13px;
            border-style: solid;        
            overflow: auto;
            border-color: rgb(174, 174, 235);
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="test" autofocus>
        <form>
            <script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/payment-button.js" data-  payment_button_id="pl_JfhYZeSvyVFaIf" async></script> 
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The modern approach is using min-content/max-content. This will auth width/height based on the content.

```
width: min-content;
height: min-content;
```