# setting div height according to the whole length of the page(beyond scrolling)

Tags: css, html

i tried to find related solutions but i coudnt find one.
First i would like to show an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/kQPA9/)
The css i used was:

```
position:absolute;
height:100%;
width: 24.5%;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
background-color: black;
```

I think something is wrong with 'bottom=0;'.
As you can see there are 2 div's: main and sub. These two divs are different from each other(as in not nested).
The main content is present in the 'sub' div. As the content is alot the page size increases (we need to scroll to see the whole content). now what i want is that the other div's height should increase based on the length of the whole page.
In my actual code there are many more divs with dynamic content so the length of the page is not fixed.
The end result i want is that the black portion should be covering the whole right side of my page, from top to end of page. now it is just ending at only the first portion of the page that is viewed initially, not beyond scrolling.
Thank you.

Comment: hi ur qs might possibly coincide with this thread pls check out.. . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920114/how-to-auto-adjust-the-div-height-according-to-content-in-it

Comment: In that thread, the div's height is adjusted according to the content present inside it. In my case the div doesnt contain any content. just the height should be from top to end of page so as to create a black portion. the two divs aren't related to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the position to fixed and it will work for you...so your css looks like...

```
position:fixed;
height:100%;
width: 24.5%;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
background-color: black;
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kQPA9/6/)

Comment: Thank you. i guess what its doing is fixing the div on the screen always. is it right?
its working fine for now.:)

Comment: Setting position:fixed will fix the position of your element relative to the browser window.
It will take your element out of the influence of the container elements.
When you set the height to 100% and position to fixed, your element wil take care of the whole window.

Answer (score 1):

Your `div` with the property `position: absolute;` should have a parent container with `position: relative;`

You could set `position: relative;` on the `body` and then adjust `margin` and `padding` to get the `div#main` to stretch the full height.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kQPA9/5/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your divs into another one with position:relative.

```
.wrapper{
position:relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kQPA9/4/

Element with position:absolute puts istselves in relation to parent container with position:relative.
If there's no such it positions itself to browser window.

Answer (score 1):

Sounded like you wanted the div to be the height of the whole page. This can easily be achieved using some simple jQuery:

```
var bod = $(document);
var body_height = bod.height();
var body_offset = bod.scrollTop();
var body_full_height = body_height + body_offset;

$("#main").css("height", body_full_height + "px");
```

this will make your `#main` div the height of the it's parent container (document).

The other solution works too, but it does not, however, make the div the height of the page (beyond scroll)

You can view the demo below.

http://jsfiddle.net/BNAGf/

Or, as mag pointed out, if you can add a new div wrapper as relative and there is no need for js.

Comment: JQuery does not belong in simple CSS solutions like this one.

Comment: Please refer to the last sentence of the answer. Also, I worked with the given components assuming that he did not want a wrapper. But Madr, you are absolutely correct. Adding jQuery, despite the minimal footprint this particular code would leave, would be a waste of system resource. Thank you for your insight. Keep coding!