# Overflow with my height

Tags: html, css

I want that my container DIV expand its height automatically when i add some DIVs with JS or CSS (hover)

I try but there is a overflow you can see it at this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L29BG/) :

HTML :

```
<div class="container" >
    <div class="hov">Hello</div>
    <div class="sub"></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.container {
    background-color: beige;
    height: 80px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;

}
.sub {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 80px;
    width: 200px;
    display: none;
}
.hov:hover + div {
    display: block;
}

.hov {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Change height attribute in .container to `auto`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to auto adjust the <div> height according to content in it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920114/how-to-auto-adjust-the-div-height-according-to-content-in-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have given *a declared* height to your `.container` the browser does not dynamically calculate the height of the container upon hover/any action where you expect the container to expand. It does work that way when it is set to `auto`, which it is set to by default.

Remove the fixed height and the `.container` will expand based on the content.

To achieve what you need, set `min-height` to `.container`. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L29BG/7/)

Answer (score 3):

Use `min-height`instead of `height`

[See JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L29BG/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Use `min-height` as René says, or remove height completely from `.container`.

Answer (score 0):

you are restricting your container div with height i.e 80px;

you get the solution by simply replacing **height** with **min-height:80px;**

the container look like after modification:

```
.container {
    background-color: beige;
    min-height: 80px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;

}
```

Comment: you have to put `min-height` in your css code not `height`