# Cannot float second div to right side of first div?

Tags: html, css

My code is very basic

HTML:

```
<div class="blog cf">
    <div class="left_article_content">
        <img width="100" height="100" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="test">
    </div>
    <div class="right_article_content">
        <h1>Test Header</h1>
        <p>
            This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test 
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block; 
    height: 0; 
    clear: both;
}

.blog .left_article_content {
    float: left;
}

.blog .right_article_content {
    float: left;
}
```

[jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/93y7ekcz/)

As you can see, my second div `right_article_content` is not float to the right side of `left_article_content`. What's the reason and how to fix it?

Comment: yes it is. what browser are you using?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ou0mu21s/ you want this?

Comment: You just remove .right_article_content{ float:left; }

Comment: A few freebies for you without changing your HTML markup. [This one with floats](http://jsfiddle.net/td79jr54/) - [this one with display:table](http://jsfiddle.net/qfwdLdb8/) - [this one with display: inline-block](http://jsfiddle.net/7bqd9e73/). Note the 50% width. Oh, and just for fun. [This one with display: flex](http://jsfiddle.net/cddrqjux/1/). Nice and simple concept.

Answer (score 0):

Your second div is trying to take up the full width, which is pushing it below the first div.  Set the width of the second div accordingly:

```
.blog .right_article_content {
    float: right;
    width: 75%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/93y7ekcz/5/

Alternatively, you could place all the content in one floated div:

```
<div class="blog cf">
  <div class="left_article_content">
    <img width="100" height="100" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="test"/>
  </div>
  <h1>Test Header</h1>
  <p>
     This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test 
  </p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/93y7ekcz/8/

Comment: Thank you. I'm just curious but is there any way to achieve the same result without setting width?

Comment: Btw, if I set width to left div only then it's not working: http://jsfiddle.net/93y7ekcz/9/ ?

Comment: I cannot change the HTML. Is there a way that allow me to set the width for the left div to `100px` but not setting any width for right div?

Answer (score 0):

Dude it's working fine on my side. Maybe your problem is the size of the browser that makes the element in the right side to move down. IT's working fine for me: BTW if you put width it will work at any browser sizes.

```
    .blog .left_article_content {
    float: left;
}

.blog .right_article_content {
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/93y7ekcz/3/

here is the full-width: http://jsfiddle.net/93y7ekcz/3/embedded/result/

Comment: I want it to be responsive so all screen size should be noted.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set width of your DIVs 
beacuse these are talking **100% width** of their **parent Div** 
that's why do not have required space in **right side** of first DIV.

```
.cf{
    width: xxxPX; 
    OR like
    min-width: xxxPX;
    overflow: auto;
}

.blog .left_article_content {
    width: xxxPX;
    float: left;
}

.blog .right_article_content {
    width: xxxPX;
    float: left;
}
```

I hope this will solve your problem.
See this for auto adjust height & width of parent DIVs
[How to auto adjust DIVs hieght & width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920114/how-to-auto-adjust-the-div-height-according-to-content-in-it/11534465#11534465)

Answer (score 0):

like others have mentioned if you do not define the height of the div it will inherit the width of its parent div. you should define the width of both the divs accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block; 
    height: 0; 
    clear: both;
}

.blog .left_article_content {
    float: left;
}

.blog .right_article_content {

}
```

code this http://jsfiddle.net/7upew2aL/

Comment: I don't have deep knowledge about that if you have than please explain me thanks for that