# How to adjust div height size depending on text length

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a box that adjusts its height depending on how long the text is. I keep trying to change height (auto, etc) or the overflow but I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is a picture of the current situation:

EDIT: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/clagos08/x0Lz9673/4/) - The overflow is set to hidden and the min-height is set to 50px but the div is still not adjust. *I only want the div height to adjust to the content not the width*

[image]

Here is my code below:

```css
.article-item-overlay {
  display: inline-block;
  height: inherit;
  margin: 190px;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
.article-item-date-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -23px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.article-item-date {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 7pt;
  font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  background: #000;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
.article-item-title {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 2.0;
  overflow: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="article-item-overlay text-center">

  <div class="article-item-date-wrapper">

    <div class="article-item-date">TITLE</div>

  </div>

  <h3 class="article-item-title">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</h3>

</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to auto adjust the <div> height according to content in it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920114/how-to-auto-adjust-the-div-height-according-to-content-in-it)

Comment: It's under the same "objective" but when I add overflow: hidden, it cuts off the title box that I want included. Additionally, by adding min height and overflow hidden, the div does not resize.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to create a box that adjusts its height depending on how long the text is.

That's the default behavior, unless you do something to change it.

In this case, you need to remove the `display: -webkit-box` property. This property value is obsolete. What did you intend for it to do? You failed to include that in the code you posted.

You could have debugged this easily enough by turning off the properties in `.article-item-title` one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Do u want this like this output check in jsbin link

[Link to jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vokagiv/edit?output)

```css
.article-item-overlay {
  display: inline-block;
  height: inherit;
  margin: 190px;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
.article-item-date-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -23px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.article-item-date {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 7pt;
  font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  background: #000;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
.article-item-title {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  display: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 2.0;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="article-item-date-wrapper">

    <div class="article-item-date">TITLE</div>

  </div>

  <h3 class="article-item-title">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</h3>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not at all - the entire title (black box) is pushed all the way down and this adjusts the width. I only want the height adjusted depending on the size of the content.