# div height not adjusting when % is adjusted?

Tags: html, css

Why is the div height in percentage not working, I setup the font to a big 30px, but when I set the div height to 10%  it is still the same height?

```css
div.ex1 {
    font: 30px arial, sans-serif;
}

div {
    height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ex1">This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph.</div>
```

The height of the block element is suppose to depend on the content, so if I set height of containing block to say 10% the div should become smaller?

Comment: Please check this link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920114/how-to-auto-adjust-the-div-height-according-to-content-in-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well look at it this way

when you say 10% .. css asks 10% of what ... parent ??
ok then it looks at body.. to get its height .. but it is not defined and it depends on the children, but child wants to be 10% of parent ...

so basically give body some height

like

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

read more here https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-height

Comment: When body height is not defined div will depend on the content not the children, and since I defined font to be 30px why is is not displaying 10% of the content?

Comment: height look at parent (containing block) , not children